# What is the best way to limit user device with which can login website

Tags: authentication, limit, device

I am developing a website with Express and React. And I would like to limit login on max 3 devices for each user.

**At first,** I tried to find the way to get **Mac address**, but I couldn't get it in browser.

**So next time**, what I tried is **to produce a random string for cookie**, and whenever changes it, store it in Database, and then when I exceed 3 rows, trigger event to tell user cannot login. But in this case, there is a disadvantage. If user clear the cookie manually or change browser, I cannot detect user login from one device. Of course I encrypt the data by crypto-js, so that user cannot change it and if he does, Browser will produce a new cookie.

```js
      let device = null;
      try{
        device = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cookies.data, SECRET).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)).device;
      }
      catch{
        console.log("JSON Parse error!");
        // make a new string and store in cookie
        device = randomString.generate(16);
        const data = {device : device, createDate: new Date()}
        setCookie('data', CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), SECRET).toString());
      }
```

Anyone can help me? Please tell me **a good way to limit a device for user to login**.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to limit any device if the app is open in at most 3 devices right? I mean not if they had logged in and closed the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data you save in browser to track, can be deleted by user. Whether it's a cookie or Local Storage or Indexed DB. So you need a mechanism to track the devices or let's say instances. A device can have multiple browsers and the user can use different browsers at the same time.

If you have noticed a feature in Gmail, we can try a similar idea. Gmail can show all the open sessions and it allows to kick out any session. How do they do it?

They are using Web Sockets. ASP.NET SignalR or Socket.IO can be used for this purpose.

A chat app uses web sockets. When you open your app it's connected to server and like a chat goes only to one person you can control the instance.

I believe you need web sockets to get this feature right.